# How to clean CD / DVD that have mold on them

Tags: dvd, compact-disc

I notice some of my favourite CD and DVD have some mold on them. How do I go about to clean them so that I can still play them?

Comment: Actually, it is very common. At least where I live (Sydney, Australia). I collect retro video games (discs) and I estimate 30 - 40% are affected with mould on the data side of the disc surface. We also get mould growing on camera lenses. I read somewhere a while back the conditions here are great for mould?

Answer (score 2):

DVD and CD are made of [Polycarbonate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycarbonate#Data_storage), usually indicated as #7 on resin code (recycling symbol).

According to [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/1095/59731):

> ... polycarbonate, which is not very soluble in ethanol or isopropanol, but prolonged exposure may cause crazing or stiffening.

That answer also mentioned that

> Most plastics and rubbers are resistant to aqueous solutions and ionic compounds (including most surfactants and soaps)

Soap is not ideal as it is a fat based product, and can leave residue.

[Detergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detergent) (a type of surfactants) is probably better, but as its chemical compond can vary a lot, it is difficult to say here.

It is safer to use distilled water first, and dry it with microfiber cloth.

There are also cleaning kits available, which I assume includes some kind of safe surfactant spray.

Comment: Cleaning kits usually use isopropanol. Which is perfectly safe for CDs.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED - 11 October 2020**

I have found dishwashing liquid is a better cleaning agent with less chemical fumes (compared to mould remover). It's also widely available and cheap.

**Step 1.**

Identify that the disc has mould growing on the surface (usually the data side). Look closely.

[image: Disc with mouldy surface]

**Step 2.**

Wash your hands with soap to remove excess hand grease and any particles that may cause scratching.

**Step 3.**

If you have a few discs to clean (3/4 at a time), arrange them near a sink with some clear bench area. You may want to use an old towel to rest them on. Grab some dishwashing liquid.

**Step 4.**

Run water slowly over the disc data side up. The water beeds on the disc surface holding it horizontal. Drip one or two drops of dishwashing liquid onto one of the beads of water.

**Step 5.**

Move the liquid around a little with your finger and then carefully add a small amount of water. Rub the disc gently with your thumb(s) in an outward circular motion for 5 - 15 seconds rotating the disc for even coverage.
Do the same for the other side.

[image: Cleaning disc surface (note: this photo (chemical spray) is from a previous answer.)]

**Step 6.**

Rinse the disc clean holding the disc between thumb and forefinger. Flick the excess water off and check the mould has been removed. If not, repeat the clean. Shake off as much water as possible.

[image]

**Step 7.**

Prepare some pieces of clean paper towel with as little amount of dusty fibres as possible. Arrange 3 drying phases of 2 pieces folded (in sequence) and a drying final resting piece. Push the disc down flat on the first phase with an additional piece of paper towel, move it to the second phase repeat and then the third phase. If the disc still has microdots of water rotate the disc in the air (not rotating while touching the paper towel) and repeat. Then leave on the resting piece. Confirm the mould is gone and the disc is OK.

[image: Paper towel phases to remove water from disc]

[image: Drying disc]

[image]

Comment: "The water is quick to run off but it just used to dilute the bleach." - what bleach? Your pet is quite confusing.

Comment: I should make a YouTube clip of my hillbilly cleaning technique and post the link here.

Comment: This site is not a good fit for posting YouTube videos, as posts should be self - containing. Instead please read again your post and try to make it more clear.

Comment: Maybe some photos will help? I thought the written description was OK divided into the three sections. Your issue is with the first sentence?

Comment: My issue is logic in your description. Your wrote need to dilute bleach, but it's not stated when and how bleach is applied. There are other similar issues too.

Comment: Tap water shouldn't be used, as it contains impurities that can be left behind on the disc  _(same reason it shouldn't be used on PCBs/components, as those impurities are conductive and can fry PCB components)_; use 90%+ alcohol or distilled water, with the former also killing microorganisms. For drying, paper towels are the worst material that could be used because the fibers within them will scratch the resin; instead, lay them on a soft towel _(not a microfiber one, as fibers from most microfiber cloths will scratch the resin in the same way they scratch clear coat)_

Answer (score 0):

The above are useful answers; however, I'm not a little gutted that I've only one item suffering from the mould problem: the DG Bach 333 box (222CDs, three books, and a DVD).  Even the interior of the lovely box is suffering, although the books aren't.  I'm totally baffled, as I bought the box on original release only three years or so ago.  As one can imagine, it wasn't cheap, and much of the contents is totally irreplaceable (there are some recordings of works made especially for the set).  The idea of losing the very, very tough and nicely-made box really does upset me.  Any ideas?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1118175)

Answer (score -2):

You mention mold, therefore I recommend using something like a mild solution of borax, which you can find in the laundry section of a grocery store. Probably under the brand-name "Twenty Mule Team," is a definitive way to eliminate and to prevent mold and fungus. Apply it to the surface and let it dry. Apply it also, using a light sprayer, to the insides of the sleeves and, once again, let it dry completely.

It's quite amazing to see what "lil' ol borax" actually does to the molecular structure of these organisms. One writer said, "it looks like a nuclear explosion hit it." (Other things that you might think to try, like bleach, don't even come close.)

I'd also suggest to make copies of the disks that show signs of damage due to the mold. If the disks are from different manufacturers and all / most the disks with the mold are of the same type, copy everything from the disks from this manufacturer to new disks.

To prevent this in the future keep your CD/DVD's in a case or a plastic wallet.